# Page Middle Click Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I need to pop-up alert when I use Middle Click and it must don't pop-up if I click it on a link but on any other element of page (or just on empty space).

```
var test = {
pageMiddleClickListener : function(e) {
    if(e.which === 2) {     
        //if (!gContextMenu.onLink) {
            alert('ok');
        //}
    }
}
window.addEventListener("click",test.pageMiddleClickListener,false);
```

Alert show-ups when I use Middle Click on a link, but I need to prevent this behavior to links

I need something like "!gContextMenu.onLink" but not for context menu (without)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways that you can test for the `target` of the click being a link. One way would be to check to see if the [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) is `A`, another would be to test for the `href` property. As it turns out is is also necessary to test to see if any of the target's `parentNode`s are links.

```
var test = {
    pageMiddleClickListener : function(e) {
        if(e.button === 1) {     
            if (!test.isLinkOrAParentIsLink(e.target)) {
                e.view.alert('ok');
            }
        }
    },

    isLinkOrAParentIsLink : function(el) {
        if (el.tagName === "A") {
            return true;
        } //else
        let parent= el.parentNode;
        while (parent !== null && typeof parent.tagName !== "undefined") {
            if (parent.tagName === "A") {
                return true;
            } //else
            parent= parent.parentNode;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("click",test.pageMiddleClickListener,false);
```

or

```
    isLinkOrAParentIsLink : function(el) {
        if (el.hasAttribute("href")) {
            return true;
        } //else
        let parent= el.parentNode;
        while (parent !== null && typeof parent.tagName !== "undefined") {
            if (parent.hasAttribute("href")) {
                return true;
            } //else
            parent= parent.parentNode;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note: I changed [`e.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which) to [`e.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) as that is what is in the specification for [click events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and [`MouseEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which) is non-standard. Note this also required testing for `e.button === 1` instead of 2.

Comment: It works now but only for a few links

If link looks like:
<a href='***'>***</a>
It's works correctly (alert doesn't pop-up)

But alert pop-ups if link looks like:
<a href='***'><'b>***</'b></a>       
                 OR <a href='***'"><span>***</span></a> (Youtube uses it for link of video)

Comment: I have updated this to test if any of the `e.target`'s `parentNode`s are links.  This solves the YouTube issue you mentioned, and should account for any others that have a structure below the link. I am also deleting my older comments which are no longer relevant.

Comment: I also found a solution and it's easier: if (!e.target.closest("a")) { alert('ok'); }

Comment: @user25, Using [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is certainly less code. I am always of two minds when using functionality that is marked on MDN as experimental. For a Firefox extension, I would normally make the choice based on when the functionality was first supported, and if that was before/after the oldest version I wanted to support with the add-on. Given that support for `Element.closest()` was only added as of Firefox 35.0, I would choose not to use it (I would generally want to support at least back to Firefox 29, or even earlier).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you have clicked an `<a>` with the `prop` method.

```
$(this).prop("tagName") == "A"
```

In your event listener:

```
var test = {
   pageMiddleClickListener : function(e) {
       if(e.which === 2) {     

        // not an <a> ?
        if ($(this).prop("tagName") !== "A") {
            alert('ok');
        }
   }
}
window.addEventListener("click",test.pageMiddleClickListener,false);
```

Comment: It would be unusual for jQuery to be available in a Firefox add-on environment.

Comment: Good point.  I made an assumption from the jQuery tag on this post.

Comment: You also have a good point that the tag is there. I must admit that I did not even look for it as having jQuery in a Firefox add-on can be a bit frustrating to set up and properly submit as an add-on to AMO such that most people don't do so. Given the tag, I should not have made the comment.