# readStringReplaceMalformed() function does not work Mozilla Firefox versions below 22?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I am new to development of Mozilla-Firefox extension . I am creating an add-on `.xpi` file for Firefox . It was working fine till today. But, today i installed a version of Firefox i.e. Firefox-15.1 and add-on started throwing Following exception:

[image]

While checking on various versions of Firefox i observed that this add-on throws same exception on versions below Firefox-22.

So can anyone tell me why this is happening so. Am i making mistake in the code, or there is any compatibility issue of Firefox ? If it is compatibility issue can you please provide me any reference documentation.

Following is my sample code causing error:

**MyJS.js :**

```js
var path="D:\\DemoExportFunction.dll";
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");      
var lib = ctypes.open(path);       
var getStr = lib.declare("getString",ctypes.default_abi,ctypes.char.ptr); 

function func_PageLoad(event) 
{   
   try  
   {
  alert("func_PageLoad");
  var str=getStr();
  str=str.readStringReplaceMalformed();
  alert("String:"+str);
  
  }
  catch(err)
  {
 alert("Exception in func_PageLoad Message : "+err.message);
  }
}

gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", func_PageLoad, true);
```

**.Dll finction code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C"
{
    __declspec( dllexport ) char * getString( );

}

char * getString( )
{
    return "Hello . . . . This is message from dll";
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about this. But jump onto irc and i can help you out in person: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsctypes

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be assuming that [CData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/CData) is static over the lifetime of Firefox. However, it has, of course, been something that developed over time (just like the entirety of Firefox, or almost any large software project). If a particular function is available in an older version of Firefox depends on when the function was implemented and included in Firefox.

As to documentation, the ultimate documentation is the [Firefox source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Viewing_and_searching_Mozilla_source_code_online). To exactly localize which version of Firefox this function was first available in, I would expect to have to look at the source code and see when it was added.  However, you can get some hints as to when this occurred from other things.

Documentation for it was added to the [CData page on MDN on Feb 19, 2013](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/CData$revision/356507). With no revisions to that page since [Aug 9, 2010](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/CData$revision/109752). It was clearly something that was an issue as of 2012-05-17 when [Bug 756120 - Complete implementation of CData readString](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756120) was filed.

The [CData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/CData) page on MDN even includes what is effectively a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) for use when `readStringReplaceMalformed()` is not available.  That code is:

```
function readAsChar8ThenAsChar16(stringPtr, known_len, jschar) {
    // when reading as jschar it assumes max length of 500

    // stringPtr is either char or jschar, if you know its jschar for sure, pass 2nd arg as true
    // if known_len is passed, then assumption is not made, at the known_len position in array we will see a null char
    // i tried getting known_len from stringPtr but its not possible, it has be known, i tried this:
        //"stringPtr.contents.toString()" "95"
        //"stringPtr.toString()" "ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x7f73d5c87650"))"
        // so as we see neither of these is 77, this is for the example of "_scratchpad/EnTeHandle.js at master · Noitidart/_scratchpad - Mozilla Firefox"

    // tries to do read string on stringPtr, if it fails then it falls to read as jschar

    var readJSCharString = function() {
        var assumption_max_len = known_len ? known_len : 500;
        var ptrAsArr = ctypes.cast(stringPtr, ctypes.unsigned_char.array(assumption_max_len).ptr).contents; // MUST cast to unsigned char (not ctypes.jschar, or ctypes.char) as otherwise i dont get foreign characters, as they are got as negative values, and i should read till i find a 0 which is null terminator which will have unsigned_char code of 0 // can test this by reading a string like this: "_scratchpad/EnTeHandle.js at master · Noitidart/_scratchpad - Mozilla Firefox" at js array position 36 (so 37 if count from 1), we see 183, and at 77 we see char code of 0 IF casted to unsigned_char, if casted to char we see -73 at pos 36 but pos 77 still 0, if casted to jschar we see chineese characters in all spots expect spaces even null terminator is a chineese character
        console.info('ptrAsArr.length:', ptrAsArr.length);
        //console.log('debug-msg :: dataCasted:', dataCasted, uneval(dataCasted), dataCasted.toString());
        var charCode = [];
        var fromCharCode = []
        for (var i=0; i<ptrAsArr.length; i++) { //if known_len is correct, then will not hit null terminator so like in example of "_scratchpad/EnTeHandle.js at master · Noitidart/_scratchpad - Mozilla Firefox" if you pass length of 77, then null term will not get hit by this loop as null term is at pos 77 and we go till `< known_len`
            var thisUnsignedCharCode = ptrAsArr.addressOfElement(i).contents;
            if (thisUnsignedCharCode == 0) {
                // reached null terminator, break
                console.log('reached null terminator, at pos: ', i);
                break;
            }
            charCode.push(thisUnsignedCharCode);
            fromCharCode.push(String.fromCharCode(thisUnsignedCharCode));
        }
        console.info('charCode:', charCode);
        console.info('fromCharCode:', fromCharCode);
        var char16_val = fromCharCode.join('');
        console.info('char16_val:', char16_val);
        return char16_val;
    }

    if (!jschar) {
        try {
            var char8_val = stringPtr.readString();
            console.info('stringPtr.readString():', char8_val);
            return char8_val;
        } catch (ex if ex.message.indexOf('malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset ') == 0) {
            console.warn('ex of offset utf8 read error when trying to do readString so using alternative method, ex:', ex);
            return readJSCharString();
        }
    } else {
        return readJSCharString();
    }
}
```

This type of change, adding the `readStringReplaceMalformed()` function, is something that is normal for development of such interfaces. It is something which you should be aware occurs and that such changes/enhancements to the API are something you, as a consumer of the API, should be aware of and their impact on your work.

### Older versions of Firefox and compatibility:

One of the tasks you should do when developing a Firefox extension is to [choose the oldest version of Firefox which you wish to support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Choosing_minVersion_and_maxVersion). You can do this by a variety of methods, but which oldest version you choose to support limits the functionality you are able to use in your add-on, or requires you to implement functionality in two, or more, different manners. For instance, there was a considerable change in how to insert/remove/change items from the Firefox UI at Firefox 29. If you are making such changes to the Firefox UI (even just adding a button) you need different code for versions of Firefox prior to Firefox 29 and Firefox 29 and later which your code has to choose to use based on the version (or the availability of the functionality). Version which have such basic and significant changes are often good choices for the oldest version to support with your add-on.

An example of an API change that I recently encountered when [answering another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594998/page-middle-click-listener/31595542#31595542) was a user wanting to use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to simplify their code. However, the choice to do so would limit that code to only be compatible with Firefox 35.0, or later. This type of choice (use new functionality vs. remain compatible with older versions) is something that you will encounter many times when writing code which interacts with other code blocks (modules, APIs, etc.).

In general, you would normally base the choice of which oldest version of Firefox to support on a variety of factors like:

1. A *need* to support customers using specific older version.
2. Availability of required functionality (is there something that your add-on needs as a core functionality that is just not available in an older version for which there is no workaround/polyfill).
3. Percentage of installed base using older versions
4. Ease of support (i.e. how much changed between versions, what additional coding to you need to do to support an older version).
5. Were you already compatible (i.e. your add-on existed prior to some major change and you had to write code to be compatible with the new version, (e.g. any Firefox add-on which was working prior to Firefox 29 and added code to be compatible with the new UI API)).
6. Many other factors

Assuming that you have no specific issues that require either an older version be supported, or a minimum version which you can support, you may want to make this decision based on a version which was an [Extended Support Release (ESR)](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/) (e.g. [24.0esr, 31.0esr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history)).

In general, you will probably want to support at least back to the most recent ESR release.

Comment: Thanks @Mayken for the MDN post, my function there isnt a replacement to `readStringReplaceMalformed` but its an alternative so it attempts to even read the malformed with `String.fromCharCode`, so no replacements are made, i havent had an issue with it successfully reading everything. :)